# Embedded UIcollectionView scrolling inside UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview, interface-builder

I have UICollectionView inside Static UITableView Cell. I want to ask how to enable vertical scrolling in UIcollectionView interface builder. what are the right settings to achieve that?
[image: fa]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You couldn't see any scrolling in the Interface Builder:) Only when compiled. 
Yes, you have right set - **Scroll direction** to **Vertical**. But... I guess, this is doesn't work for you?
If you set custom layout for collection view in code - you have to setup it.